# Is OpenGL implementation completely different on different platforms?

Tags: opengl

Some tutorial told me OpenGL's context is specific operating-system, we have to use WGL, EGL, GLX etc. for creating context. Do they tell OpenGL instance how does the context look like? or OpenGL implementation is fully different on different platforms?

Comment: So is implementation specific windowing system?

Comment: And for example, driver on windows OpenGL can only understand WGL's context?

Comment: But WGL create the context, so OpenGL should obey WGL, is it right?

Comment: Or opposite, the WGL obey OpenGL?

Comment: [WGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGL_(API)) is an API between OpenGL and the windowing system interface of Windows. I recommend to read [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 1.3.6 Window System Bindings](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=28&zoom=100,168,442)

Comment: The context is specific operating-system, so can I say OpenGL driver on windows is an OpenGL implementation of WGL's context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it like the mail.

In order for a letter to properly get through the mail, it must have a valid address on it. Address validity is defined by the particular mail system you're using, with respect to various applicable laws, customs, and so forth. But this system is clear for anyone to read and can get a letter from anywhere to basically anywhere. Addresses, within a particular mail system, work the same for everyone.

But everyone has a different *mailbox*. Everyone has a different place that they put a letter in order for it to get where it's going.

The specific people who pick up the letter are different people for different locations. The letter processing centers are different, as are the truck drivers, airplanes, and so forth. All of the stuff that needs to happen to transport a letter from its source to its destination are going to be different for different sources/destinations.

But they all work in accord with the same addressing system. A user of the mail system doesn't care about the minutiae; if they put the right address on the letter (and postage), then it will (theoretically) get where it's supposed to go.

The address on your letter is like OpenGL. It's a standard that everyone understands. It describes how to convert an address into a location to send a letter/how to interpret rendering commands to produce an image.

Your particular mailbox is like the WGL or GLX or EGL interface for creating a context. They are the means by which you *access* the process of sending a letter to an address/rendering via OpenGL. The address has the same meaning regardless of which mailbox you put it in.

Your mail carrier is like the OpenGL implementation/context. It does the actual work of making sure the letter goes to the location as defined by the address standard/executing the rendering commands on the GPU to render in accord with the OpenGL standard.

---

There is one exception to this analogy: the [default framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer). The default framebuffer in OpenGL represents images owned by the operating system/window manager/etc. As such, the composition of the default framebuffer is defined in the process of creating the OpenGL context. Context creation parameters can affect whether it has back/left/right buffers, the presence of a depth and/or stencil buffer, the format of its images, etc.

Comment: So the implementation need to develop for all mailboxes, but how does implementation know which mailbox(context type) used?

Comment: @AlanJian: How does the letter carrier pull mail out of a mailbox? As a person sending a letter, you *don't need to know;* that's up to the designer of the box and the letter carriers themselves. The same goes here; unless you're trying to write an implementation of OpenGL or to write an operating system or similar structure, it is irrelevant. It's a matter between two parties, neither of whom is you.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry about that, I wasted a lot of time to think about how does manufacturer do that